# Want to make iframe go fullscreen when clicked

Tags: iframe

When you click on the 'featured properties' (which is simply iframed from my friends other site) it obviously attempts to open the website within that iframe, is there a way to code that so when clicked, it opens in full in another page?

Source: http://wiredpractice.com/jcr.html (it's in temporary housing right now)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to utilize this feature on an anchor tag:

```
<a target="_blank" >...</a>
```

You can use it on an existing link you've setup inside your iFrame or wrap your iFrame with an anchor tag that has the correct link and target property.

I'd recommend this site for more detail: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp